# Selectors with props are deprecated

Tags: javascript, angular, ngrx, ngrx-selectors

On the 2nd line, I am getting this error: Selectors with props are deprecated.

```
const getUserProfileState = createFeatureSelector<UserProfileState>(authorizationFeatureKey);

const hasPermission = createSelector(
    getUserProfileState,
    (state: UserProfileState, permission: GQLPermission): boolean => {
        const result =
            state.permissions &&
            state.permissions.some((p) => p && p.resource === permission.resource && p.action === permission.action);
        return !!result;
    }
);

const hasCreateCasePermission = createSelector(getUserProfileState, (state: UserProfileState): boolean =>
    hasPermission.projector(state, {
        resource: PermissionResource.case,
        action: PermissionAction.create,
    })
);
```

I am trying to refactor "hasPermission" function like this:

```
const hasPermission = (permission: GQLPermission) => createSelector(
    getUserProfileState,
    (state: UserProfileState): boolean => {
        const result =
            state.permissions &&
            state.permissions.some((p) => p && p.resource === permission.resource && p.action === permission.action);
        return !!result;
    }
);
```

But I am having difficulty in how to refactor based on this hasCreateCasePermission .

Answer (score 0):

Side note: The use of `.projector` in the first sample is a bit of a smell.
You can do the following:

```
const hasCreateCasePermission = hasPermission({
        resource: PermissionResource.case,
        action: PermissionAction.create,
});
```

Comment: Hi, but " const hasCreateCasePermission = createSelector(...)", createSelector is being used here. so does removing that achieves the same functionalty?

Comment: Yea, `hasPermission` creates the selector instance